# IE click on a button that has no link associated to it (using Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I want to click on a "button" on a web page, but my problem is that this button doesn't seem to have link attach to it.  By the way I'm phrasing this you can see I'm not familiar at all with the language of web browser.
Anyway I most use internet explorer  and here's the code I have so far

```
Sub click_button_no_hlink()


Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")               'create IE instance

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://apex.xyz.qc.ca/apex/prd1/f?p=135:LOGIN_DESKTOP::::::"  ' Adress of web page

Do While IE.Busy                                                     'loading page
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

'-------------Usually I would do something like that and it would works well.-----------------
Set link = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each l In link
    a = l.innerText
    If l.innerText = "Créer" Then                    '
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
'-------------That method works fine on other type of hlink to the page by the way------------


'-----------------------I also tried various methods around this with no luck------------------------------
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("rc-content-buttons")                  'recherche du bouton "Créer"
'---------------------------------

'--------------------or this also doesn't work-------------------------------
For Each btn In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("rc-content-buttons")
    If btn.getAttribute("id") = "B91938241817236808" Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next btn

End Sub
```

For sake of clarity here's the code of the web page around the "button" I'm trying to interact with.
[image: javascript code]

I've made many research but I'm in a dead end right now.  Any help will be greatly appreciate.
Tx in advance.

SOLVED FINAL CODE:  With help from DOMENIC and QHARR and Yu Zhou

```
Sub click_button_no_hlink()


Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")               'create IE instance

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://apex.xyz.qc.ca/apex/prd1/f?p=135:LOGIN_DESKTOP::::::"  ' Adress of web page

While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend             'loading page

IE.document.querySelector("[value='Créer']").FireEvent "onclick"   'works like a charm

            '  IE.document.querySelector("div.rc-content-buttons input").Click         
                     'also works but speaks less by itself when reading code
            '  IE.document.getElementById("B91938241817236808").Click
                     'also works 

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the target element doesn't have an inner text.  But it does have an ID.  So try `IE.document.getElementById("B919...").Click`.

Comment: Hello @Domenic, tx for the suggestion.  I believe  I tried that already without success.  I'll try it first thing in the morning tomorrow and will let you know.  In the meanwhile if someone else has another idea to suggest I'll also try it in less than 12 hours.  Tx all

Comment: Please explain what without success means. Did you get an error when trying Domenic's suggestion?

Comment: @Domenic your solution works perfectly well!!  I thought I tried it but it seems I didn't.  Tx for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is within an input not a tag element so gathering a tags will not capture what you want. Using the id, as suggested in comments is one way to go. If you get element not found then check whether your element is within a parent frame or iframe which needs to be negotiated. General syntax for that is

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(appropriateIndexHere).contentDocument.getElementById("B91938241817236808")
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(appropriateIndexHere).contentDocument.getElementById("B91938241817236808")
```

If the id is dynamic you can use the `value` attribute

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='Créer']")
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(appropriateIndexHere).contentDocument.querySelector("[value='Créer']") 'etc
```

As there is an event, you may need to fire it.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='Créer']").FireEvent "onclick"
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(appropriateIndexHere).contentDocument.querySelector("[value='Créer']").FireEvent "onclick"  'etc
```

And use a proper page load wait. So this,

```
Do While IE.Busy                                                     'loading page
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

Should be

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents:Wend
```

Comment: Thank your very much QHarr!  Indeed the ID method works, but the querySelector is more elegant since code is more self explanatory when reading "value='Créer" then reading "B91...".   It wasn't in a frame, but it's an event so I had to use .FireEvent.    I've also modified my load page wait loop.  Gained some seconds there.  Many thanks.  I should have posted this sooner instead of searching by myself for 4 hours..

Comment: I have a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416534/internet-explorer-click-an-icon-and-a-button-of-a-specific-line-of-a-table, anybody (@QHarr maybe) could help?

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names, so I think it should be `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("rc-content-buttons")(0).Click` if it is the first element with the classname.

You could also try: `IE.document.querySelector("div.rc-content-buttons input").Click`.

And I think `IE.document.getElementById("B91938241817236808").Click` is also right.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Tx Yu Zhou your 2nd suggestion  (querySelector(…).Click also works