# Internet Explorer click an icon and a button of a specific line of a table

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I've asked a similar question two days ago but I know stumble again on a similar problem but somehow different.  [previous question asked on a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383500/ie-click-on-a-button-that-has-no-link-associated-to-it-using-excel-vba)

I have a report of many lines with the same structure.  I need to click an icon that is on the nth line.  That report is structured in cells so I know that my icon is in the first position (column)  of that report.  After I have click that icon I'll also have to click on a button in the  10th column.

I already know how to access the page in question with that code

```
Sub click_button_no_hlink()


Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")               'create IE instance

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://apex.xyz.qc.ca/apex/prd1/f?p=135:LOGIN_DESKTOP::::::"  ' Adress of web page

While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend             'loading page
```

This first part is easy isn't?  And I know how to handle it.  Afterward I tried different variation around this but it either do nothing, or I get an error message.  Obviously I don't fully understand what I'm doing with the "querySelector" thing…

```
dim step_target as string
step_target = 2

'identify all the lines of my table containing lines, containing icons 
'and button to click on
Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("highlight-row")       
i = 0
Do While i < objCollection.Length
'cell 2 is the one containing the step I'm targetting
    If objCollection.Item(i).Cells(2).innerText = step_target  Then                  
    'that's not doing anything    
   objCollection.Item(i).Cells(9).Click
   'tried many syntax around this with no luck
    IE.document.querySelector([objCollection.Item(i).Cells(9)]).FireEvent ("onclick")       
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Here's images of the code of the page

Showing all the lines of the report
[image]

Showing all code lines of a particular line

[image]

and now the code of that first icon I need to click on (this is where I need help ;-) how can I call that action) 
[image: and]

and finally the code of that button I also need to click on
[image]

Again, I thank you all in advance, for the time you'll take to help me along this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try attribute selector for first in combination with descendant combinator and `a` type selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[headers='ID_DET_DEM_TRAV_STD'] a").click
```

you could try attribute selector for second in combination with descendant combinator and `input` type selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[headers='BOUTON1'] input").click
```

alternative for second is

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value=Fait]").click
```

Typically, if you want to select by position e.g. 1 and 10th columns you would use

```
td:nth-of-type(1)
td:nth-of-type(10)
```

Though you would also use a `tr:nth-of-type(n)` to get the right row as well e.g. first row, first col. Then add in any child type selector, for example, that you might need.

```
ie.document.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1)")
```

Child `a` tag:

```
ie.document.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1) a")
```

Child `input` tag:  would then be:

```
IE.document.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(10) input").Click
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr,  the first two suggestion works fine if I would want to select the first line's button and icon.  I tried adding the line ie.document.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1)") but it doesn't do anything.  Sorry, there's something I don't understand in that syntax.  Could you give me another chance and be a little more specific?  Tx again

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1)") only selects the td. You need to add in another type selector for a child element that can be clicked e.g.  ie.document.querySelector("tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1) a").click

Comment: Tx QHarr!!  Works perfectly well

Comment: No worries. nth-of-type is useful for positional selection particularly with tables. It is only available when using internetexplorer.

Comment: so what will happen the dayIE is replaced?  Is there an equivalent to nth-of-type?

Comment: what I meant is that the nth-of-type selector is not supported when using XMLHTTP. It requires browser automation such as IE. Also, works with selenium basic automation of other browsers so I expect it to be supported in any future browser automation libraries in VBA. This is where VBA is lacking (and many other languages) versus Python where there are a few libraries implementing a much wider range of css selectors.

Comment: anything you can do with nth-of-type you can likely specify in another way but you might have longer selectors.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors